# Reset a for loop inside a switch statement

Tags: java

The code that I have runs, but when I do the `do-while` loop, the `for` loop does not reset back to 1 when the user chooses `Yes` to rerun the program. I hope I am making myself clear.

```java
int choice;
int num;
int i;
String input; 
int b = 1;
```

```java
switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        do {
            System.out.println("The starting number is 1.");
            //Input
            System.out.print("Enter a value: ");
            num = sc.nextInt();

            for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
                b = b * i;
                //Output
                System.out.printf("%d! = %d\n", i, b);
            }

            System.out.print(
                "Run the program again? (Y for Yes, N for No): ");
            input = sc.next();
        } while (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
            System.out.println(
                "Have a great day!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        break;
}
```

I tried a `while` loop instead of the `for` loop and I was not getting the results at all. I am new to Java so I am still learning.

I added a `break` at the end of the `for` loop, but that ends the loop only after 1 increment.

Comment: What do you mean the for loop doesn't reset to 1? The for loop starts from one every iteration, even after the user enters 'Y'. Your question is unclear

Comment: Perhaps you could edit the question to include examples of input, expected results, and actual results.

Comment: Is your actual issue with `b`? There's no reason for it to be anything other than whatever it was prior to the loop. If you want `b` reset then reset it. The loop variable will certainly always be what it's supposed to be.

Comment: `b = 1;  for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `switch` expression. Also, declare the variables in the narrowest scope. In this case, except for `sc`, they should be declared in the do/while loop, or in the case of `b`, in the for loop.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println("The starting number is 1.\n");
            System.out.print("Enter a value: ");
            // Input
            int num = sc.nextInt();

            for (int i = 1, b = 1; i <= num; i++) {
                b = b * i;
                // Output
                System.out.printf("%d! = %d\n", i, b);
            }
    
            System.out.print(
                "Run the program again? (Y for Yes, N for No): ");

            String input = sc.next();
    
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                System.out.println(
                    "Have a great day!");
                sc.close(); 
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } while (true);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me what I was doing wrong with the for loop. I am new to Java and I am still learning.